# GCMRegistrar vs Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn how to use GCM, I just learned that there are two different APIs, what I don't understand is why google has [this](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/) registration page while it didn't require that for the old GCM for the user notifications? assuming that User Notifications is the push notification.

and is the User Notifications the same as the Push Notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GCMRegistrar](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html) is deprecated and should not be used. [User Notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html) are **not** available in the old API and are not exactly the same as push notifications. Instead, user notifications seeks to build a single `notification_key` which represents every device the user has downloaded your app on. This allows you to send a single GCM message to all devices and, if you use upstream messages (also not available in the old API), send a message to all other devices.